# "He paid back all the money he owed her" or "He paid her back all the money he owed"

Tags: sentence-construction

I have a question about where to use the object of a verb in a certain sentence.

When you are talking about someone who owed someone else money and then paid it back, which is the normal way of saying this?

> He paid back all the money he owed **her**.
>
> He paid **her** back all the money he owed.
>
> He paid **her** back all the money he owed **her**.

I first thought of using "her" after both verbs, but then I thought, perhaps I should omit either because the object of the verb should be obvious without its being said twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentences seem to have slightly different nuances. In the first example it's not clear who he's paying to, but that he is paying how much he owes her.

The second does not make it clear to who he owes the money.

The third removes ambiguity.

That said, the third sounds a bit redundant. The nuances I described can be mostly ignored and assumed from context anyway. I would prefer the second sentence, but they all look fine.